# NUnit: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, razorengine

When running NUnit tests in TeamCity, I keep getting the following error.

```
Test(s) failed. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.Block..ctor(BlockType type, IEnumerable`1 contents, String name)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.Block..ctor(BlockType type, IEnumerable`1 contents)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.SyntaxTreeBuilderVisitor.VisitEndBlock(BlockType type)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.VisitorPair.VisitEndBlock(BlockType type)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.ParserContext.EndBlock()
   at System.Web.Razor.Utils.DisposableAction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Web.Razor.Utils.DisposableAction.Dispose()
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.HtmlMarkupParser.ParseRootBlock(Tuple`2 nestingSequences, Boolean caseSensitive)
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.HtmlMarkupParser.ParseDocument()
   at System.Web.Razor.Parser.RazorParser.Parse(LookaheadTextReader input, ParserVisitor visitor)
   at System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCodeCore(LookaheadTextReader input, String className, String rootNamespace, String sourceFileName, Nullable`1 cancelToken)
   at System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(TextReader input, String className, String rootNamespace, String sourceFileName, Nullable`1 cancelToken)
   at System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(TextReader input)
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.CompilerServiceBase.GetCodeCompileUnit(String className, String template, ISet`1 namespaceImports, Type templateType, Type modelType)
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.Compile(TypeContext context)
   at RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext context)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String template, Type modelType)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.GetTemplate(String template, Type modelType, String name)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse[T](String template, T model, String name)
   at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse[T](String template, T model, String name)
   at MyProject.CachedRazor.Parse[T](String aTemplateRazor, String aTemplateName, T aModel) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bb723c0e2c1dace\MyProject\CachedRazor.cs:line 62
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at UnitTests.Tests.EmailRazorParsingTests.EmailRazorTemplate_ParseSucceeded(EmailRazorTemplateNames aEmailRazorTemplateName, Type aEmailModelType) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bb723c0e2c1dace\UnitTests\Tests\EmailRazorParsingTests.cs:line 47
```

I found some answers related to very long methods in the code, but they don't seem relevant. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you're using outdated mvc distribution at the CI server? It's possible that it generates IL for 3.5 framework, or somthing of that sort.

Comment: That's the target app throwing the exception, so nothing to do with nunit. Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251433/nunit-on-release-build-common-language-runtime-detected-an-invalid-program/21953367#21953367 ?